# How to prevent back button from firing on .click()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, click

I have a simple bit of JavaScript that is swapping a video thumbnail for the embed video hidden behind it on a user click:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready( function(){
         $(".video-image").click(function(){
         $(".video-embed").css({"opacity":"1","display":"block"});
         $(".video-embed")[0].src += "&autoplay="+autoplay;
         $(this).unbind("click");
        });
    } );
})(jQuery)
```

I also have a form on the same page that, when submitted, takes the user to a thank you page. If the video on the homepage is either paused or still playing when the form is submitted, and then the user chooses to hit the back button from the thank you page, the video on the homepage will begin playing again. I believe this is because JavaScript treats the back button as a .click event.

Basically, I want to prevent the back button from executing the JavaScript. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Is this not a case of forcing autoplay to false. Then when someone clicks inside the ".video-image" image you bring the video to the front and start it using the javascript?

Comment: is that not what I am doing? i think my problem has to do with the .click(function()... firing when i hit the back button. so regardless of what state my autoplay is in, it's still going to fire.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that changing a frame source technically counts as changing the page, at one point I was making a video player that just changed the source of an iframe, but every time the source changed you'd have to hit back again - so if you clicked 5 videos, you'd have to hit back 6 times to get to the previous page!

The solution is to generate and destroy the frame instead of switching the source - something like this for your event:

```
$("container .video-embed").remove();
$(container).append("<iframe class='video-embed' src='url here'></iframe">
```